# Protecting APIs keys on Git-hosted Ruby project

Tags: ruby, github

I'm not really sure where to start with this. I'm making a Ruby project that interfaces with a dictionary API, and uses an API key. I don't want anybody and his uncle to be able to see this key, but the project will have to be hosted on GitHub. How can I go about doing this, and accessing the key from the Ruby program?

Clarification: this is for a class, and we have to use GitHub

Comment: what about bitbucket?

Comment: It's for a class. We have to use GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you'd put such things in a file like this:

```
DICTIONARY_API=key_goes_here
```

and check in a version of the file (named `.example` or `.sample` or something) which just contains blanks:

```
DICTIONARY_API=
```

Or you could read the key from the environment, using `ENV`. If you host on Heroku, this is recommended. See also the `Dotenv` gem and the `ENVied` gem.

I've seen both methods combined (especially when using `Dotenv`) by making a .env file for local/non-heroku usage, and using Heroku's config settings on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Figaro gem. [Documentation](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

Basically you will use a file called application.yml and store environmental variables. Double check that application.yml is listed in your .gitignore file so nobody can view it on github.

You could set:

```
# application.yml
API_KEY: my_api_key_here
```

And then you could set it to another variable in your app with:

```
# anywhere in your app
api_key = ENV['API_KEY']
```

For production, you can use Figaro's commands to sync your env variables with Heroku.